# Modify HTML elements with php web hook

Tags: php, callback, webhooks

I am just about done implementing an API that I'm so far very happy with, see [Talk js](https://talkjs.com/). As for this moment I am implementing web hooks to be able to display the n amount of unread messages that a given user **U** have. The web hook "callback" is a local php file on the web server which the **talk js** server will ping upon certain actions.

**SEE: web_hook.php**

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$event = json_decode($input);
switch ($event->type) {
case "message.sent":
    //psudo
    if($event->receiver->id == $signed_in_id){
       update_n_unread_messages();
    }

    break;
case "message.read":
    //Given action
    break;
case ....
}
```

**The problem**

Normally whenever I need to load database information or other types of dynamic data I would do it with an XHR-request in javascript and process the information within a callback. However I don't see how I would be able to do something of the sort here. The client never sees this request, it's a request between the ***talk js*** server and my web server. So how do we update HTML elements from our server side php web hook callback. Any type of help is much appreciated.

Comment: your questions is extremely hard to read ... methinks you still need to learn about client/server architecture and how websites actually work. Well your solution is quite simple : store your events in your database and have XHR requests retrieve the last known ones ... you could also implement a proper websocket and push updates to the clients immediately - that'd save some storage space and a few CPU cycles ... and probably traffic

Comment: Either your clients need to constantly _pull_ the server for new information in a sensible interval, or you need to implement a _push_ from the server-side to all currently active clients - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology